# mod_rewrite redirects every page to homepage

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a problem with mod_rewrite on www.decraciun.biz
It seems every page is redirected to homepage.
My .htacces file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thank you,
Radu-Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Your .htaccess file redirects every request that isn't a file or directory to the homepage.

The `RewriteCond ... !-f` line ignores any requests for files that exist, and `RewriteCond ... !-d` ignores any requests for directories that exist. In other words, if someone requests a file or directory that exists, the URL will not be rewritten. Otherwise, the `RewriteRule` line is used. It matches any URL and rewrites it to `index.php/` followed by the requested URL.

Are requests for existing files or directories also redirecting to the homepage?

Comment: If you access "Despre noi" tab, the requested url is www.decraciun.biz/despre-noi. This should be redirected to www.decraciun.biz/index.php/despre-noi but it does not. It loads me the homepage. If I tipe the url www.decraciun.biz/index.php/despre-noi in the browser it works and loads the desired page.